# Htaccess - Redirect destination to sub folder with the same name and same file name.php

Tags: .htaccess, model-view-controller

I’m using a framework called TWA found here on GitHub: https://github.com/twaframework/twaframework

You don’t have to know the framework to answer this question but you can check it out if it helps.

Basically, this framework has a `web_content` folder in the root. This folder then has a folder inside called `pages`
Then, inside the `pages` folder are folders named all the titles of the pages we have.

So, for example, there is a `home` folder in `/web_content/pages/home`

The main file in all of these pages folders are named after their page as well:

```
/web_content/pages/home/home.php
```

Or

```
/web_content/pages/overview/overview.php
```

Note that I’m trying to work on this through xampp, so the files are all being served through my localhost.

I’ve searched every where for `.htaccess` rules that can successfully do this:

Redirect `localhost/SkyDev/home` or `localhost/SkyDev/overview` to:

`localhost/SkyDev/web_content/pages/home/home.php` and
`localhost/SkyDev/web_content/pages/overview/overview.php`

Note that `SkyDev` is the name of the project folder in htdocs of xampp. Also, I need it so that no matter what I type after `SkyDev/`, it will follow this rule and try to find the folder and file with that name. I don’t JUST need it to work for `home` and `overview`. Also, the redirect should NOT change what I type into the URL. It should just bring me to the correct files.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This sounds like something the "framework" should already do, with a front-controller type pattern? ...and yes, a quick check in the default `.htaccess` file on github shows a front controller - everything is already rewritten to `index.php`. I would expect this to already route such requests (if this is how the framework is intended to work)? Is this the file you are using? Is there some problem with this? If you implement a rewrite (not a redirect) as you suggest then you are basically overriding the framework - is that the intention?!

Comment: _Aside:_ "Note that I’m trying to work on this through xampp, so the files are all being served through my localhost." - Just because you are using XAMPP doesn't mean you need to use localhost (which you seem to imply). XAMPP uses Apache. Ideally, you would create a separate `<VirtualHost>` for each project, with its own `DocumentRoot`. Then the files can be served from anywhere. (Map a domain using your HOSTS file if you need to.)